# О словах "порука" и "ручательство"

Tags: значение-слов, значение

Могут ли слова "порука" или "ручательство" использоваться в отношении к неодушевленным предметам, отвлеченным понятиям?

Например: Расписание - порука организации учебного процесса. Благодатная почва - порука обильного урожая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могут.

> Там живут - и **песня в том порука**
>
> Нерушимой, дружною семьей
>
> Три танкиста - три веселых друга
>
> Экипаж машины боевой.

[«Три танкиста»](http://www.9maya.ru/2015/09/25/pesnya-tri-tankista-tri-veselyh-druga-slushat-skachat-tekst.html)

Comment: А предложения правильно составлены, как Вы думаете? Из словаря: ПОРУКА, . Ручательство в чём-л.; подтверждение чего-л. Получается: Расписание - подтверждение организации учебного процесса. Благодатная почва - подтверждение обильного урожая. Это правильно? Может быть, так нужно:  Правильно составленное расписание - порука в  успешной организации учебного процесса. Благодатная почва - порука в получении обильного урожая. Или все правильно в заданном вопросе?

Comment: @Sharon, лично я бы написал **"порука в ..."**, но цитаты из Нац.корпуса показывают допустимость обоих вариантов. Например: **"Даже на московских всё забывших улицах у него сохранилось, что только слово "солдат" ― порука искренности и дружелюбия человека"** *(с) Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 26-51 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990*